# Using the Matlab Engine in a WinRT Application

Tags: c++, matlab, opencv, windows-runtime

When I try to include the Matlab engine library (libeng.lib) I get a runtime error claiming

```
   Unhandled exception at 0x77DED4F2 (ntdll.dll) in Application1.exe: 0xC0000135: Unable to Locate DLL.
```

However my linker settings are all fine, the same properties work fine on a non RT C++ project. I'm also suspicious that it is referring to ntdll.dll rather than the libeng file I am trying to include.

I also attempted to include the OpenCV library and received the exact same error.

I am brand new to RT development and I'm guessing it has something do do with how apps are 'deployed' before being run. Has anyone run into this kind of thing before and can shed some light on my problem? Thanks.

Comment: This is probably not possible, as WinRT restricts the use of external libraries. Have you had any success/workarounds on this?

Comment: No. As you suspected there is no work-around that I know of.